# If I am not able to find patent then can I consider it expired?

Tags: patent-applications, patent-lifetime, expiration

I downloaded a patent from internet and when tried to find its status that if it is active even today or not was not able to find on Intellectual Property of India website even by searching it from every aspect of it and tried it finding it with its title then found no patent on the date mentioned on the patent either from application date and publication date and patent was also done from India only.
What could it possibly mean for the patent status?
Or did I made any mistake in finding it?

Comment: Please tell us the document number or better yet a link to the document so we can help you.

Comment: No patent office I know deletes data from their website if the patent expires. So I strongly suspect that the answer is no.